# How can I show that a sphere is rolling in a simulation?

Tags: graphics3d, simulation

I recently wrote code to simulate a table tennis ball rolling on the ground.

```
v0 = 10; w0 = 8; R = 4; mu = 0.2; g = 9.8;
δ = (2 (v0 + w0 R))/(5 mu g);
```

This gives the ball's location

```
location[t_] = 
  Piecewise[
    {{If[t <= δ, 
        v0 t - 1/2* mu*g*t^2 + R, 
        (3 v0 - 2 w0 R)/5 (t - δ) + v0 δ - 1/2* mu*g*δ^2 + R], 
      3 v0 - 2 w0 R < 0}, (*<0 roll back*)
      {If[t <= δ, 
         v0 t - 1/2* mu*g*t^2 + R, 
         v0 δ - 1/2* mu*g*δ^2 + R], 
      3 v0 - 2 w0 R == 0},
      {If[t <= δ, 
         v0 t - 1/2* mu*g*t^2 + R, 
         (3 v0 - 2 w0 R)/5 (t - δ) + v0 δ - 1/2* mu*g*δ^2 + R], 
      3 v0 - 2 w0 R > 0}}]; (*>0roll front*)
```

and this gives the rotation angle

```
zhuanjiao[t_] = 
  If[t <= δ, 
    w0 t - (3 mu g )/(4 R) t^2, 
    w0 δ - (3 mu g )/(4 R) δ^2 - (3 v0 - 2 w0 R)/(5 R) (t - δ)]; (*>0 roll front*)
```

This implements the simulation.

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[
    Rotate[Sphere[{location[t], R, R}, R], -zhuanjiao[t], {0, 1, 
    0}, {location[t], R, R}] , 
    Method -> {"SpherePoints" -> 10},(*lower the sample to show roll*)
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, {0, 2 R}, {0, 2 R}}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}
  ], {t, 0, 2 (2 (v0 + w0 R))/(5 mu g) + 10}]
```

My question is: my way of showing that the ball is rolling is to lower its sample. Which is kind of uncomfortable and ugly. Is there better way to do so?

It is hard to show that a sphere is rotating. If I don't do what I've done, it looks like it sliding on plane, not rolling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you might do it by putting spots on the sphere. However, if you were to do that, you would the rotation you have imposed is not the rotation of a rolling ball. At least, it doesn't look it to me.

The following demonstrates a set of points, located on the surface of a ball, being moved and rotated by your functions `location` and `zhuanjiao`. Evaluate it to see what I mean.

```
R = 1;

v0 = 10; w0 = 8; mu = 0.2; g = 9.8;
δ = (2 (v0 + w0 R))/(5 mu g);

location[t_] := 
  Piecewise[
    {{If[t <= δ, 
        v0 t - 1/2* mu*g*t^2 + R, 
        (3 v0 - 2 w0 R)/5 (t - δ) + v0 δ - 1/2* mu*g*δ^2 + R], 
      3 v0 - 2 w0 R < 0}, (*<0 roll back*)
      {If[t <= δ, 
         v0 t - 1/2* mu*g*t^2 + R, 
         v0 δ - 1/2* mu*g*δ^2 + R], 
      3 v0 - 2 w0 R == 0},
      {If[t <= δ, 
         v0 t - 1/2* mu*g*t^2 + R, 
         (3 v0 - 2 w0 R)/5 (t - δ) + v0 δ - 1/2* mu*g*δ^2 + R], 
      3 v0 - 2 w0 R > 0}}]

zhuanjiao[t_] := 
  If[t <= δ, 
    w0 t - (3 mu g)/(4 R) t^2, 
    w0 δ - (3 mu g)/(4 R) δ^2 - (3 v0 - 2 w0 R)/(5 R) (t - δ)]

Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[
    Rotate[
      Translate[Point[SpherePoints[100]], {location[t], R, R}],
      -zhuanjiao[t],
      {1, 0, 0}, (* changed to get rolling to look right *)
      {location[t], R, R}],
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 2 R}, {0, 2 R}},
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}],
  {t, 0, 1, .01}]
```

Comment: If you use the positive version of `zhuanjiao` and `{0, 1, 0}` it seems to rotate appropriately. I also put a `Sphere[]` inside the `Translate` as that made it a little bit clearer what was going on, to me.

Comment: sorry for be so late to reponse. since there is a little mistake in the code.`-zhuanjiao[t], {1, 0, 0},` seems to be `-zhuanjiao[t], {0, 1, 0},` . the final effect nice. thx. it takes me sometime to find it :)

Answer (score 9):

Any reason why you want to show a `Sphere`? To my mind using another shape would be a lot more fun. Here's [m_goldberg's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) code with a demo from [`SphericalPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html):

```python
myWheel = 
  SphericalPlot3D[
   .8 + Sin[5 ϕ]/5, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[.9], Specularity[White, 10]], 
   Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 30
   ];

frames =
  Table[
   Graphics3D[
    Rotate[
     Translate[
      myWheel[[1]],
      {location[t], R, R}
      ],
     zhuanjiao[t],
     {0, 1, 0},
     (*changed to get rolling to work*)
     {location[t], R, R}
     ],
    Axes -> True,
    AxesEdge -> {{1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}},
    Ticks -> None,
    Boxed -> False,
    Lighting -> "Neutral",
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 2 R}, {0, 2 R}},
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
    ViewPoint -> 4*{1, -2, .5}
    ],
   {t, 0, 1, .05}
   ];

rast = Rasterize[#, ImageResolution -> 144] & /@ frames;

CloudExport[rast, "GIF", "test.gif", "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

[image]